# Is it possible to define default resources for a Ballerina service?

Tags: ballerina

Trying to see if i can expose
curl http://localhost:9090/studentinfo?schoolId=12341324,
where "studentinfo" is the service path.

```
    @http:ServiceConfig { basePath: "/studentinfo" }
    service<http:Service> studentInfo bind studentInfoListener {

            @http:ResourceConfig {
                methods: ["GET"],
                path: "?"
            }
            getStudentBySearch(endpoint client, http:Request req) {

                http:Response response;

                var params = req.getQueryParams();
                var schoolId = <string>params.schoolId;
                var addmissionYear = <string>params.addmissionYear;
            ...
            }
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ballerina, Request is dispatched based on both path and HTTP verb. When it comes to a default resource, both path and verbs should not constrain the request. Please consider following code snippet.

```
@http:ResourceConfig {
    path: "/*"
}
getStudentBySearch(endpoint client, http:Request req) {

    http:Response response;

    var params = req.getQueryParams();
    var schoolId = <string>params.schoolId;
    var addmissionYear = <string>params.addmissionYear;
...
}
```

Here HTTP verb is not specifically stated. That means any verb is allowed.

When path is defined as "/*", any path segments which comes after the basePath will be matched to it in the absence of a specific match.

Sample URLs:

> http://localhost:9090/studentinfo?schoolId=12341324,
>
> http://localhost:9090/studentinfo/resourcePath?schoolId=12341324
>
> http://localhost:9090/studentinfo/name -X POST

Answer (score 1):

Using just "/" as the resource path should work.

```
@http:ResourceConfig {
    methods: ["GET"],
    path: "/"
}
```